# Is there inline x86 asm that can be faster than gcc's llround?

Tags: gcc, floating-point, inline, x86-64

Is there an x86 inline asm solution that can take a double, multiple by 100.00, and then convert to an integer. The "input" double is effectively a price and I'd like to convert to "cents" as an integer.

Assumptions that can be made.

- The double won't be NaN, Infinity or signed zeroes.
- The double will be positive
- The conversion may require some rounding.  Eg: 8.19999 should become 820
  as an integer.
- SSE4 instructions are available
- The data arrives serially
- GCC >=4.7 is the compiler of choice.

To phrase it differently, when using gcc 4.7.x and compiling with -O3, --fast-math, is there an x86 asm approach that will be better than this type of code?

```
#include <math.h>
int cents = llround(price*100.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to go ahead and write a conversion function assuming that the input is less than 2^52/100:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*@ requires 0 <= d < 0x1.0p52 ; */
long long cents(double d)
{
  d = d * 100. + 0x1.0p52;
  long long l;
  memcpy(&l, &d, sizeof(double));
  return l & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
}

int main()
{
  printf("%lld\n", cents(0.994));
  printf("%lld\n", cents(0.996));
  printf("%lld\n", cents(123456789.004));
  printf("%lld\n", cents(123456789.006));
}
```

The expected result is:

```
99
100
12345678900
12345678901
```

`gcc -O2` compiles the computations part of my function `cents()` to:

```
mulsd   LCPI1_0(%rip), %xmm0
addsd   LCPI1_1(%rip), %xmm0
movd    %xmm0, %rcx
movabsq $4503599627370495, %rax
andq    %rcx, %rax
```

You may want to inline it or to tell your compiler to inline it. This may or may not be faster than `llround()` depending on your processor.

If you have a fused-multiply-add instruction available, then `d * 100. + 0x1.0p52` can be computed in a single instruction, but what costs anyway is loading the constants. If you have to do many of these in a loop, leave the constants in registers (or tell the compiler that it can do so).

---

An alternative is to add `0x1.fffffffffffffp-2` (the `double` immediately below `0.5`) and to truncate to `long long`:

```
long long cents(double d) { return d * 100. + 0x1.fffffffffffffp-2; }
```

The rationale for using `0x1.fffffffffffffp-2` instead of `0.5` is that it gives you the nearest integer in all cases where there is one. By contrast adding `0.5` gives you the farthest of the two nearest integers in some cases (details, with type `float` instead of `double`, in [this post](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/02/nearbyintf1)). In exchange you have to give up the property that ties (`0.125`, `0.625`, …) are rounded away from zero: by using `0x1.fffffffffffffp-2` they get rounded down.

You know why my example to illustrate ties is `0.125` and not `0.005`, don't you? If not, never mind.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answer. From my limited testing, it looks like its about the same if maybe just a clock tick slower. I keep thinking there must be a way to set the FP rounding register to get it done with something with a mul and a cvtsd2si.

Comment: @EricJohnson I have added a method that should compile to multiplication by 100., addition, and cvtsd2si.

Comment: For me, the second cents implementation produced the same x86 as your first, but perhaps I have made a mistake and will try again.

Comment: @EricJohnson It is highly unlikely that the compiler generates the same code for the two solutions, because they do not produce the same results for exact ties or for numbers above 2^52.